# Is it possible to only screenshare a specific UIView using AppScreenSource?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, arkit

Is it possible to only screenshare a specific UIView using AppScreenSource?

I'm creating an iOS app which is using RealityKit to place virtual objects on screen. I'd like to share this video with the other connected user in the room.  AppScreensource seems like an almost perfect solution, but I don't want to share the entire screen - just my ARView.  Is there a way to do this?  Or do I need to go another route?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the doc. I don't find any solution for capturing a portion of the screen. `AppScreensource` will the whole screen.

Link to the docs - https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios-v4-screen-capture

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use ARView's instance method [snapshot(saveToHDR:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/snapshot(savetohdr:completion:)-66jzu). There is a working example mentioned in [this blog](https://betterprogramming.pub/take-an-arview-snapshot-in-realitykit-93b620cf99b3).